# Mail function stops working while using a domain name as messgae content

Tags: php, email, gmail

Below script was working fine till when i changed the message to "domain.org". Now its showing success message but im not receiving any emails even not in spam. If I change the message to "domain.com" its working fine.

```
    $from = "info@domain.com";
    $to = "testmail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "domain.org";
    $headers = "From:". $from;
    $mail = @mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    if($mail){
    echo "Test email sent";
    }else{
    echo "Mail not sent";
    }
```

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Could you remove @ from @mail and post errors if any ?

Comment: Check your mail server logs.

Comment: @ vincenth, yes i tried using both mail and @mail, but not working.

Comment: @ Synchro, k I will check it.

Comment: Just stating the obvious but, the fact mail() returns true means the e-mail was accepted for delivery. According to the documentation "just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination". Have you tried to add more text along with the domain ?

Comment: @vincenth, yup tried that too. Still fails.

Comment: @Amith, what happens if the domain in $message is the same than the one in $from ? Could you try : $from = 'info@domain.org'; $message = 'domain.org'; ?

Comment: @vincenth, tried many changes like that but its working only when i change the $message value. for ex. domain.com,domain-org etc are working. I think the domain name is black listed! is there any possibility for that?

Comment: @vincenth, if i change the $message value as "wordpress.org" its fine.

Comment: Thanks, Please upvote the question also.